# Backbone - How to use specific extended model while fetching collection?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js

I'm trying to create a Wordpress theme using Javascript, Requirejs and Backbonejs.

In the index route, I instantiate a new postsCollection `app.postsCollection = new Posts.Collection();` which will contain all WordPress posts. Then, I run .fetch() `app.postsCollection.fetch( { success: ..., error: ... } );`

Here is the code of my **modules/posts/collection.js** file :

```
define( function( require, exports, module ) {

"use strict";

var app       = require( 'app' );
var PostModel = require( './model' );

var PostsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend( {

    model   : PostModel,
    url     : app.jsonApi + "get_posts/",

    parse: function( response ) {

        return response.posts;

    }

} );

module.exports = PostsCollection;
```

} );

## My problem :

I'd like to extend the PostModel defining `var ImagePostModel = PostModel.extend( { ... } );` and `var GalleryPostModel = PostModel.extend( { ... } );`. Then, I'd like to use the specific model while fetching, thanks to the post type (image or gallery) of collected data. How can I do this ?

Comment: You can use a function for your collection's [model](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) property that will return the appropriate model.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jack. I don't know how I missed it in the doc ...

Comment: I don't think that was always in the documentation, it might have been added with the 1.1 release.

Comment: I started working with Backbone when the 1.1 has been released ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general for backbone properties you can instead of specifying the object directly use a function that return an object, for example you can provide a function that returns an object for the events hash. The same is true for the model property.

Instead of specifying a model for your collections `model` you can instead use a function that will based on some condition return the appropriate *model type*.

From the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model)

> A collection can also contain polymorphic models by overriding this property with a constructor that returns a model.

And the provided example

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: function(attrs, options) {
    if (condition) {
      return new PublicDocument(attrs, options);
    } else {
      return new PrivateDocument(attrs, options);
    }
  }

});
```